# Dependency of dependency; Framework 4.6.2 dependencies in .net Core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependencies

I have a 3rd party library that targets .Net Framework 4.6.2 (x86).  I'm on an x64 Windows machine, with the x86 sdk installed.  I need to figure out if/how I can use this library in my aspnetcore3.0 project.  Can someone elucidate an approach taking into account the considerations below?

I've included the external library as a `Reference` with a `HintPath` in my csproj file for an Asp.Net Core 3.0 project.  I'm currently publishing as a framework-dependent deployment (FDD).

Some elements of this library seem to work just fine, whereas other methods error out.  From what I can tell, the library's `Initialize` method uses `System.Data.SqlClient` to connect to a MSSQL source.  I've included logic to call this in a hosted `BackgroundService` that gets added in `ConfigureServices`.  When the code hits this point, it errors out with:

```
The ConnectionString property has not been initialized
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.PermissionDemand()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.PermissionDemand(DbConnection outerConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(String connectionString, CommandType commandType, String commandText, SqlParameter[] commandParameters)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(String connectionString, CommandType commandType, String commandText)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(String connectionString, String spName, Object[] parameterValues)
... (proprietary library methods call to database)
```

A limitation of this library is that the calling executable needs to run (per `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)`) from a specific "special" directory.  Let's call it C:\MySpecialProgram\CustomApiCode.  It's a statically defined location, and I've not determined a way to work around it. This folder contains the DLL, and several other dependent DLLs.  I previously tried publishing as a single, self-contained executable, but perhaps for reasons relating to how this "package" is unloaded, the library reports that it isn't running from the special directory.

I've tried publishing from VS2019, from command line, specifying the x86 dotnet.exe and not.  They all seem to yield slightly different errors (for probably obvious reasons.

Other than the ConnectionString error above, I often get: `Could not load file or assembly {insert some System library here}. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.`  At first, it called out System.Data.SqlClient, so I added that via NuGet to try and alleviate it.  Now it seems to be choking on `System.Text.Encoding.CodePages, Version=4.1.2.0`/  Feels a little like wack-a-mole indicating that my approach is all wrong.

Comment: As an aside, I'd be curious what this library does, if there is a more modern version and / or a newer library to do the same. Based on the problems you describe with requiring a specific path etc... It sort of sounds like junk I'd be tempted to eliminate.

Comment: If only... it's a vendor provided API for critical software in our enterprise.  It's a necessary evil, and I'm stuck using it.  There's no better option at this point.  Best I could do would be to side step it entirely, and hit the database directly.  For obvious and non-obvious reasons, this isn't feasible.

Comment: Having just fought weeks of bad events from mixing .NET Core and full .NET Framework DLLs in the same project, consider hosting the full .NET framework code in a separate process, behind a WebAPI, etc, with appropriate firewall protection so that the full .NET framework code can run inside of a full .NET framework process.

Mixing full .net with .net core in the same application supposedly works, but my team wasted man-months before giving up and running them in different EXE processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET Core (any version) doesn't technically support .NET Framework libraries. Since .NET Core 2.0+ implements .NET Standard 2.0 and .NET Framework 4.6.1+ implements .NET Standard 2.0, Microsoft made an exception in the compiler to allow including .NET Framework libraries, with the caveat that they may or may not *actually* work. You should have actually received a warning to this effect upon referencing the library.

The largest majority of .NET Framework functionality is actually supported in .NET Core, but many things are not, particularly Windows-specific APIs. If the library doesn't end up working (because it makes use of APIs not supported by .NET Core), *there is no workaround*. You simply cannot use that library. Simple as that.

This is just a convenience that was added because there's a ton of .NET Framework libraries out there, many no longer under active development, but would actually work just fine with Core. There are no guarantees about ultimate support, expressed or otherwise.

That said, previous versions of ASP.NET Core <3.0, can actually target .NET Framework instead. That would allow you to use .NET Framework libraries even if they aren't compatible with Core, because you're actually targeting .NET Framework, rather than .NET Core. However, .NET Core 3.0 implements .NET Standard 2.1, which no version of .NET Framework does or ever will. As such, you can no longer target .NET Framework with ASP.NET Core 3.0 apps. If you *must* use these libraries, you can build ASP.NET Core 2.2 apps targeting .NET Framework, but you will be forever stuck at 2.2 until you move off these old libraries.

Comment: I was just thinking SqlClient wouldn't have been too heavy a lift to be compatible.  I tried targeting 462 from 2.1 (i had already built it out on 2.1 before 3.0) and no joy.  I give up.  I'm going to build out a separate .net framework component that will talk to the asp.net core server with SignalR.  Next hurdle is getting a .net framework signalr client to talk to that .net core signalR server.  I understand that they're not necessarily compatible... but I hear Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client will work for me if I specify the TransportType as WebSockets.